# Summing of count result at same level

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to sum the results of count(id) at the same level, in order to find out the relative portion of the count(id) from the overall count.

The count is grouped by the respective previous number, and I want to stay at the same table and have it all together.

`

```
select totalattempts, count(totalattempts) allattempts, count(case when success>0 then totalattempts else null end) successfulattempts
    from ( 
 
            select *, case when success> 0 then attemptspresuccess+1 else attemptspresuccess end totalattempts
                from (select orderid, count(orderid) attemptspresuccess, count(case when recoveredPaymentId is not null then recoveredPaymentId end ) success from (
                        select orderid, recoveredPaymentId
                            from errors
                            where platform = 'woo'
                        ) alitable
                group by orderid) minitable ) finaltable
group by totalattempts
order by totalattempts asc
```

`

I need to add another column that basically would have, to put it simply, count(totalattempts)/sum(count(totalattempts).

I'm running out of ideas basically.

I can't use windows as this is an app of retool which doesn't support that

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. It much easier for us to process rather than retro-engineering the current query.

Comment: please provide the sample data with the expected results of the data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some test data here:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (AttemptNumber INT IDENTITY, Success BIT)
INSERT INTO @table (Success) VALUES
(0),(0),(0),(0),(1),(1),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(1),(0),(1),(0),(0),
(0),(0),(1),(0),(0),(0),(0),(1),(0),(1),(0),(0),(0),(1),(0),(0)
```

I sounds like you want to know how many attempts there were, how many were successful and what that is a percentage?

```
SELECT COUNT(Success) AS TotalCount, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Success = 1 THEN 1 END) AS SuccessCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Success = 1.0 THEN 1 END)/(COUNT(Success)+.0) AS SuccessPct
  FROM @table
```

```
TotalCount  SuccessCount    SuccessPct
--------------------------------------
32          8               0.2500000000000
```